# update TextView in fragment A when clicking button in fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments sitting side by side in the same activity. When I touch a button in the right fragment (fragment B), I need a TextView in the left fragment to update (fragment A). I have looked all over for the best way to do this, but nothing seems to work for my needs. Could someone possibly give me an example of how I would code this? Fragment A is set through the XML layout, and fragment B gets loaded programmatically into a container. I have tried accomplishing this by using a method in fragment A to update the text, and calling on that method from a method in the parent activity. I then call on the method in the parent activity from fragment B.

This is the code in fragment B that declares the interface and calls a method in the interface

```
AttackCards attackCards; 

public interface AttackCards {
    public void deckSize();
}

public void onAttach(DeckBuilder deckBuilder) {
    super.onAttach(deckBuilder);

        attackCards = (AttackCards) deckBuilder;
        }

attackCards.deckSize(); //this is in my onclick methods
```

This is the code in the activity that implements the interface and calls the method in fragment A

```
public class DeckBuilder extends Activity implements AttackCards{

public void deckSize() {
    DeckBuilderFragment deckBuilderFragment = (DeckBuilderFragment)getFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.deckbuilder_fragment);
    deckBuilderFragment.deckSize();
}
```

This is the method in fragment A that appends the textview with the contents of a shared preferences value

```
public void deckSize() {
deckSize = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.decksize);  
final SharedPreferences defaultDeck = getActivity()
        .getSharedPreferences("defaultDeck", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
deckSize.setText(String.valueOf(defaultDeck.getInt("decksize", 0)));
}
```

Sadly this attempt simply brings me a nullpointer when touching a button. I am getting a null pointer at

```
attackCards.deckSize(); //this is in my onclick methods
```

Could someone please help me out with an example of how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface in `Fragment` B and implement it on the MainActivity. Then on the callback method (onClickOnB in this case) set the text on the `TextView`. You should obtain a reference of the `TextView` in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`. This works because `Fragment` A is static. Otherwise, you can create a public method inside `Fragment` A so you can set the text from inside the callback by getting a reference of `Fragment` A and calling such method.

`Fragment` B

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements onClickListener{
ClickOnB listener;
public void setOnFragmentBClickListener(ClickOnB listener){
this.listener = listener;

}

@Override

public void onClick(View v){
//stringMessage is a `String` you will pass to `Fragment` A to update its `TextView`
listener.onClickOnB(stringMessage);
}

interface ClickOnB{
public void onClickOnB(String message);
}

}
```

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ClickOnB{
@Override   
protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

//Get a reference of `Fragment` B somewhere in your code after you added it dynamically and set the listener.
((FragmentB)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentB")).setOnFragmentBClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClickOnB(String message){

//Set the text to the `TextView` here (I am assuming you get a reference of the `TextView` in onCreate() after inflating your layout.

mTextView.setText(message);

}
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the interface in fragment A that I declared in fragment B, but I still got a null pointer. I have changed my code to use interfaces but communicate through the activity as sjdutta suggested, but I am still getting the null pointer. Do you see anything in my updated code that could be causing this?

Comment: Thank you so much Emmanuel! It was pointing me in the direction of editting the TextView from the activity that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

One fragment should not communicate to another fragment directly. It should do so through attached activity. The detail explanation with code example is available here

[Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Declare an interface in Fragment B, and implement the interface in the activity. Call the interface through callback in Fragment B when button is clicked. You can have a public function in Fragment A to update the TextView, so activity directly call the function to update the text.

Comment: Ok I am now using interfaces as explained on the developer site. However I am still getting a null pointer. I am updating my question now to reflect the new code.

Comment: What is showing in the null pointer exception? Did you initialize the callback in onAttach() function?

Comment: Sorry, I have added my onAttach code in my edit. I can post the logcat nullpointer info if you would like.